# Pyspark: Retrieve row value based another row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Let's say, I have the following simple Spark Dataframe.

`threshold = ?`

```
ID        percentage
B101        0.3
B101        0.3
B202        0.18
B303        0.25
```

As you can see above, I have to get the `threshold` value based the ID column. for example, if  `ID == B101`, the threshold value becomes `threshold = 0.3`. if `ID = B202`, then the threshold get a new value and becomes `threshold = 0.18`. The same logic works for the rest. Like this, I have thousands of value and I would like to do this in a simple way.

I tried this:

```
threshold  = df.first()['ID']
```

But I think there should be a loop to go over all the values.

Can anyone help with this in Pyspark?

Comment: so in the end, are you going to have multiple thresholds for each ID?

Comment: Actually, I was looking for updating/overwriting the ```threshold``` value when one particular ID is mentioned in the data frame. So, every time for each particular ID, the threshold value has only one value.

Comment: I'm still not following, please show some pseudo code/function that describe your expectation better. I think the owner of answer below also confused what what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

Your DF:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('B101', '0.3'),
        ('B202', '0.18'), 
        ('B303', '0.25')
    ],
    ['ID', 'Percentage']
)

+----+----------+
|  ID|Percentage|
+----+----------+
|B101|       0.3|
|B202|      0.18|
|B303|      0.25|
+----+----------+
```

A function that will return the Percentage based on an given ID:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def threshold(ID):
  return df.filter(F.col('ID') == F.lit(ID)).collect()[0][1]]
```

calling the function:

```
threshold('B303')

Out: '0.25'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could it be possible  to implement when a value from ID is in the operation, assign the corresponding percentagr to the threshold automatically? I mean without calling specific ID using a function. Since I have thousands of IDs.

Comment: Do you have a list of IDs and you want to have the percentage associated to it?

Comment: Yes I have but, the thing is the list of IDs are not fixed. New IDs might come at some point. That is why I didn't consider using ```for this ID, use this percentage``` logic. 

I would like to zip like ```(ID, Percentage)``` so that for that particular ID, the calculation consider using that percentage.

Comment: Have you thought of creating a dataframe from those IDs and join with the dataframe with IDs and Percentage?

Comment: Not really. Though I didn't the point as well. Do you mean creating a data frame for each IDs?

Comment: I don't get it exactally what you want to do. Can you explain in more details what "when a value from ID is in the operation" means?